# How to move an element after another element using JS or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to move one `DIV` element beside another, it is normally like this:

```
<div class="box-content-top">
 <div class="box-related-product-top">
  <div>  

    <div class="price">
      ...   
    </div>              
    <div class="image">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="name">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
     ...
    </div>


   <div>  

    <div class="price">
      ...   
    </div>            
    <div class="image">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="name">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
     ...
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the position of the `div` with the class `.price` to be after the `.name` class, to look like this:

```
<div class="box-content-top">
 <div class="box-related-product-top">
  <div>  

    <div class="image">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="name">
     ...
    </div>
     <div class="price"> // HERE
      ...   
    </div> 
    <div class="cart">
     ...
    </div>


   <div>  

    <div class="image">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="name">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="price"> // HERE
      ...   
    </div> 
    <div class="cart">
     ...
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this html created? what language would you like to use to move in? your question is not very clear.

Comment: @ROYFinley the question is tagged with javascript and jquery

Comment: It's always good to attach a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m6djm/

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use `insertAfter` to move the element. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)

```
$('.price').each(function() {
    $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent().find('.name'));
});
```

Here you have the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6djm/101/).

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.box-related-product-top > div').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.image').appendTo(this);
    $(this).find('.name').appendTo($(this));
    $(this).find('.price').appendTo($(this));
    $(this).find('.cart').appendTo($(this));
});
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/m6djm/1/

Comment: this is it , tanks my bro ^_^

Comment: @user1989195 Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98135/208061 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93970/208061

Answer (score 0):

`<div>`'s are block-level elements so that's their natural behavior. You could float the div's and then clear them, or use `display: inline`.

I think this link would help you understand a bit more though:

[CSS block and inline](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/)

Comment: The question is not how to place the content of the div on the same row as the content in another div. It is about moving a div in the DOM and placing it after another div.

Comment: Ah, I see. Looks like I read 'change the position of the div' too quickly. Looks like it was solved though. Win some/lose some.