# How to find particular class named div and position other class named div below it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

for example i have four different div with class named as " class A,class B,class C ,class D"
and also  have another class name class E all div with these class name are on different part of screen now i want to find class A and below Class A want to position another Class A, how to make it possible

in html it looks something like this

```
<div class="another_class">
<div class="A"></div>
<div class="B"></div>
<div class="C"></div>
<div class="D"></div>
</div>

<div class="A"></div> // this is another class A want to position this below class A
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move an element after another element using JS or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549125/how-to-move-an-element-after-another-element-using-js-or-jquery)

Comment: How does your positioning work? You mean change the order in the html itself or by css?

Comment: 'class A' is a subcommet that i want to position below its parent comment 'class A'

Comment: can you please take a look at my updated question the another class i want to position have same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) method.

```js
var a = $('.a')[0];
var a2 = $('.a')[1];

$(a2).insertAfter($(a));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="c">C</div>
<div class="d">D</div>
<div class="a">A</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use jquery's [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.E').insertAfter($(".A"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="another_class">
  <div class="A">a</div>
  <div class="B">b</div>
  <div class="C">c</div>
  <div class="D">d</div>
</div>

<div class="E">e</div>
<!-- want to position this below class A -->
```

Comment: I want this  system for appended div (dummy). I have tried this code, it works but only when i refresh the page it doesn't work on dummy that destroys on every page refresh.